# Full screen Firefox Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to start a full screen page in Firefox with Selenium in Python 3. The page opening works fine, but when I send the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to the browser (the **Full Screen** key), anything happens. Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('http://localhost')
firefox.maximize_window()

body = firefox.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
body.send_keys(Keys.F11)
```

Does anyone know how to make my page start in full screen ? I know it's possible with Chrome, but it's harder with Firefox

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://localhost')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body').send_keys(Keys.F11)
```

Hope this helps

***Just realized I am using Python 2.6 vs your 3. Sorry about that, but at least you know it will work on an older Python version***

Answer (score 2):

Selenium has a built-in method to make the window fullscreen: `fullscreen_window()`

[Selenium API - fullscreen_window()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

> Invokes the window manager-specific ‘full screen’ operation

```py
browser.get("https://www.screenku.com")
browser.fullscreen_window()
```

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting that this is the workaround for Firefox. It does not work on Chrome nor Edge (I needed to set options to go fullscreen with these two ones)

Comment: i feel silly it took this long for me to find.  works with `python 3.8.1` `Selenium 4.3.0`, and `Firefox 60.1.0esr (64-bit)`, with `Geckodriver v 31`.  Prob works up through FF 90 ESR as I use that for a different project.

also, use `driver.maximize_window()` to un-fullscreen your browser

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install selenium pyautogui

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0")
profile.update_preferences()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get("https://www.screenku.com")
pyautogui.press('f11')
```